# Как лучше организовать подсчёт счёта

Tags: python, list

В целях изучения программирования делаю игру 21, уже довольно долго думаю как организовать подсчёт карт. На данный момент думаю насчёт туплей в тупле, но возвращать то приходится всё равно стринг..

```
def make_deck(self):
        numbers = (("6", 6), ("7", 7),  ("8", 8), ("9", 9), ("10", 10), ("Jack", 2), ("Queen", 3), ("King", 4), ("Ace", 11))
        suits = ("Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs")
        deck = []
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            count = 0
            while count < 4:
                deck.append((numbers[i][0] + " " + numbers[i][1]) + " of " + suits[count])
                count += 1    
        return deck
```

Вопрос к более опытным людям - в какую сторону смотреть, что бы проще организовать подсчёт карт? Я думал потом разбивать итоговый стринг по пробелам, выводить для юзера определённые знаки, а функции подсчёта давать только цифры веса карт. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не очень хорошая идея в плане оптимизации и в целом.

Comment: Храните данные в понятном для программы (т.е. содержащим минимум информационного шума, и не требующим никакого парсинга) виде, а конвертируйте в понятный для пользователя вид (строка, картинка, музыка, анимация) непосредственно перед демонстрацией этому пользователю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mожно туплы, можно класс сделать под карту.

> возвращать то приходится всё равно стринг

Возвращать из функции можно что угодно.
Вот показывать пользователю в текстовой игре -- стринг.

Склеивать проще, чем парсить. Храните в структурированном виде.

---

K ООП я отношусь спокойно. Его плюсы заметны на сложном проекте, и со статической типизацией.

Что за "сложность"? На вашем примере (предположим):

- вы начнaаете путаться, что на какой позиции в тупле лежит
- вы начнaаете путаться между разными по смыслу туплами.

Вот, нашел такую возможность:

```
from collections import namedtuple 
Card = namedtuple('Card', 'title,value')
card = Card("Ace",11)
print(card.title)
print(card)
print(type(card))
```

У `namedtuple` можно брать элементы по имени и смотреть тип.

Comment: Пока писал ответ, додумался что можно использовать дикт, где ключ - карта, а вес - стоимость карты) Думаю должно получится. Спасибо)
А можно поподробнее про "класс под карту"? У меня немного проблемы с пониманием ООП на данный момент, не хватает знаний синтаксиса питона) Я собирал колоду с самого начала вообще в deque в отдельном классе, просто ради изучения ооп. Все эти self не до конца понятно где и как и пихать)

Comment: @Sciti The Candyborn , добавил про ООП

Comment: благодарю, но тут скорее мои проблемы с изучением) Я всё таки самоучка, я понял что такое ООП, но вот фактического применения понять пока не могу, кроме как импорт другого класса(как у вас в примере). Просто то, что я пишу сейчас, не такое уж и объёмное для ООП мне кажется. Плюс не до конца понимаю использование ООП в питоне, опять же import ещё понятно что делает, зачем добавлять self в каждую функцию, при использовании объекта класса и __init__ тоже почитал и понял, а вот где и когда применять self.func() при вызове функции например не понимаю. Но спасибо :)

Comment: 1) У меня в примере **создание** класса `Card` под вашу игру 3) Я в основном пишу на scala, и мне кажется, что self и init в питоне сделаны некрасиво

Answer (score 3):

```
def make_deck(self):
    numbers = (("6", 6), ("7", 7),  ("8", 8), ("9", 9), ("10", 10), ("Jack", 2), ("Queen", 3), ("King", 4), ("Ace", 11))
    suits = ("Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs")
    deck = []
    for name, number in numbers:
        for suit in suits:
            # deck.append(f"({name} {number}) of {suit}")   # не как строки,
            deck.append((name, number, suit))               # a как кортежи
    return deck
```

---

*Результат — значение возвращённой переменной `deck`:*

> ```
> [('6', 6, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('6', 6, 'Spades'),
>  ('6', 6, 'Hearts'),
>  ('6', 6, 'Clubs'),
>  ('7', 7, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('7', 7, 'Spades'),
>  ('7', 7, 'Hearts'),
>  ('7', 7, 'Clubs'),
>  ('8', 8, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('8', 8, 'Spades'),
>  ('8', 8, 'Hearts'),
>  ('8', 8, 'Clubs'),
>  ('9', 9, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('9', 9, 'Spades'),
>  ('9', 9, 'Hearts'),
>  ('9', 9, 'Clubs'),
>  ('10', 10, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('10', 10, 'Spades'),
>  ('10', 10, 'Hearts'),
>  ('10', 10, 'Clubs'),
>  ('Jack', 2, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('Jack', 2, 'Spades'),
>  ('Jack', 2, 'Hearts'),
>  ('Jack', 2, 'Clubs'),
>  ('Queen', 3, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('Queen', 3, 'Spades'),
>  ('Queen', 3, 'Hearts'),
>  ('Queen', 3, 'Clubs'),
>  ('King', 4, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('King', 4, 'Spades'),
>  ('King', 4, 'Hearts'),
>  ('King', 4, 'Clubs'),
>  ('Ace', 11, 'Diamonds'),
>  ('Ace', 11, 'Spades'),
>  ('Ace', 11, 'Hearts'),
>  ('Ace', 11, 'Clubs')]
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. В Питоне не нужно итерировать по индексам, а прямо по элементам списка / кортежа:

   ```
   for suit in suits:
   ```
2. Из кортежа можно получить отдельные элементы через запятую:

   ```
   for name, number in numbers:
   ```
3. Вместо конструкции сложной строки с применением оператора `+` возможно применить f-строки:

   ```
   f"({name} {number}) of {suit}"
   ```
4. Вместо списка строк сделайте список кортежей, см. пункт 2 как из них получить отдельные элементы:

   ```
   (name, number, suit)
   ```
5. Вместо циклов возможно использовать *генератор списка*, т.е

   ```
   deck = [(name, number, suit) for name, number in numbers for suit in suits]
   ```

   вместо

   ```
   deck = []
   for name, number in numbers:
       for suit in suits:
           deck.append((name, number, suit))
   ```

   и даже возвратит его прямо в команде `return`, вез предварительного присвоения, чем ваша функция может оказаться слишком короткой:

   ```
   def make_deck(self):
       numbers = (("6", 6), ("7", 7),  ("8", 8), ("9", 9), ("10", 10), ("Jack", 2), ("Queen", 3), ("King", 4), ("Ace", 11))
       suits = ("Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs")
       return [(name, number, suit) for name, number in numbers for suit in suits]
   ```
6. Вместо кортежа парей `numbers` вы можете более наглядно создать 2 самостоятельные списки

   ```
   names = "6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King Ace".split()     # список ["6", "7", ..., "Ace"]
   nums = (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 11)
   ```

   В случае необходимости вы всегда можете склеить их обратно в соответствующие пары применением стандартной функции `zip()`:

   ```
   numbers = zip(names, nums)
   ```

   и даже создать из них словарь:

   ```
   dict(zip(names, nums))
   ```

   > ```
   > {'6': 6,
   >  '7': 7,
   >  '8': 8,
   >  '9': 9,
   >  '10': 10,
   >  'Jack': 2,
   >  'Queen': 3,
   >  'King': 4,
   >  'Ace': 11}
   > ```

Comment: Спасибо, но я пытаюсь всё сделать сам) Думаю рано или поздно я бы тоже пришёл к этому виду, но я новичок как в программировании, так и в алгоритмах. Недавно до меня дошло, что я могу не использовать range(len(numbers)) ибо в этом нет никакого смысла, не знаю под чем я это написал если честно..

Comment: *«не знаю под чем я это написал если честно»* - Вы наверно в прошлом встретились с плохими примерами. Их к сожалению много, прежде всего от программистов, которые перешли к Питону из других языков программирования.

Comment: *«Думаю рано или поздно я бы тоже пришёл к этому виду»* - я об этом уверен. :-) Я моим ответом хотел только сократить время, чтобы оно было ближе к «рано». ;-) Желаю много счастия.